# How to pass a variable in a batch script during execution

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a text file that has the record of all the services in a server. I want to keep '#' for the few entries at the beginning of the line. I have created one vbscript file that contains the following code:

```
Const Readpurpose  = 1
Const Writepurpose = 2
strServiceMonFile = WScript.Arguments(0)
strOldText = WScript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = WScript.Arguments(2)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strServiceMonFile, Readpurpose)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strServiceMonFile, Writepurpose)
strNewText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)
objFile.Write strNewText
objFile.Close
```

In order to execute the code, I am using a batch file and the code used is as follows:

```
cscript D:\Users\krkarthi\Desktop\replace.vbs "D:\Users\krkarthi\Desktop\test.txt" "Windows Update" "#Windows Update"
```

In the above mentioned batch code, I need to manually enter each and every entry which I need to keep # comment and for a plenty of services it is very difficult to proceed. I am thinking another way to have a separate text file lets say test1.txt that contains all the unwanted entries. A variable will define in a for loop to run on test1.txt and will run the above mentioned `cscript` code after `do`. The imaginative code is as follows:

```
FOR /f %%G in (D:\Users\krkarthi\Desktop\test1.txt)
DO
cscript D:\Users\krkarthi\Desktop\replace.vbs "D:\Users\krkarthi\Desktop\test.txt" "%%G" "#%%G"
```

Unfortunately, the above code didn't work at all. I don't understand where the error exists.

Comment: All 3 lines of the batch file must be on one line. Open a command prompt window and run `for /?` for help explaining the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing one % from the parameters in your code. It should work. Also you will not need double quotes while passing values to your code.

Corrected:

```
FOR /F %%G IN (D:\Users\krkarthi\Desktop\test1.txt) DO cscript D:\Users\krkarthi\Desktop\replace.vbs "D:\Users\krkarthi\Desktop\test.txt" "%%G" "#%%G"
```

Comment: That's right @Mofi I have corrected the code. Totally forgot that it was batch file while trying. Thanks! Above corrected code worked for me.

Comment: I suggest to change the batch file command line to `FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test1.txt") DO %SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\replace.vbs" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\test.txt" "%%~G" "#%%~G"`. Then this command line works for any user account independent on `PATH` and `PATHEXT` and also for lines in `test1.txt` (content not posted by questioner) containing spaces or strings being enclosed already in double quotes in the text file.